# CSS add html element

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component

I have a small website (Ubuntu, Apache2, PHP) and every page on this website has a similar content: The name of the website on the top, the navigation bar, some contact information, like my e-mail, and so on. Is there any way to add these elements through CSS? So that I only have to include this CSS file and I have the title on my page? Here's a example:

```css
#navigation {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id=navigation>
            <nav>
                <a href="/somePage.html">Some page</a>
                <br>
                <a href="mailto:test@example.org">Contact admin</a>
            </nav>
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
    
      Some long test to see, that the navigation bar is sticky
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I want that this navigation bar appears on every new page if I just include the CSS file. I tried with the following code:

```
body:before {
 content: "<nav>[Content]</nav>";
}
```

but it seems like this can only add text. Maybe you could achieve this with JavaScript? But if yes how?

Comment: You are correct, `content:` is text-only. Yes, you _could_ achieve this through javascript, but this sort of thing is usually done through some kind of _templating_. How you do templating depends a great deal on what server technology you are using — Apache? IIS? Running PHP backend? Java backend? Nodejs backend? A CMS (Content Management System)? ... It would help if you described your setup.

Comment: You can also use "client-side HTML include" https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/html-includes/ : iframe that is replaced by it's contentdocument content when JS is enabled.

Comment: @Stephen P: Do you need some more setup information?

Comment: I like connexo's solution and I have cases where I'll use it in the future. "client-side HTML include" like @ myf says works too, _IF_ your webserver supports it, which is why I asked about your server setup. My current project uses Java on the server and there is a _JSP_ include it can use; PHP (probably) has its own facilities (but I don't know PHP well enough to say) — CSS _alone_ won't be able to do it, given the limitations of 'content:'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a small webcomponent that outputs exactly that:

```js
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `<div>
    <nav>
        <a href="/somePage.html">Some page</a>
        <br>
        <a href="mailto:test@example.org">Contact admin</a>
    </nav>
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div>`;

class MyWebsiteHeader extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}

customElements.define('my-website-header', MyWebsiteHeader);
```

```css
#navigation {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<my-website-header id="navigation"></my-website-header>

Some long test to see, that the navigation bar is sticky
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
gdfgdfgdfg
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br> Hi!
```

Here's a version that completely replaces the web component with your HTML:

```js
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `<div id="navigation">
    <nav>
        <a href="/somePage.html">Some page</a>
        <br>
        <a href="mailto:test@example.org">Contact admin</a>
    </nav>
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div>`;

class MyWebsiteHeader extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.outerHTML = template.innerHTML;
  }
}

customElements.define('my-website-header', MyWebsiteHeader);
```

```css
#navigation {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<my-website-header></my-website-header>

Some long test to see, that the navigation bar is sticky
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
gdfgdfgdfg
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br> Hi!
```

Comment: You are missing the CSS part :)

Comment: @Roy: I read your comment after I had already added it.

Comment: @Rotstein - note that in a real page (not a snippet) you will want to put your component in a `.js` file and will have to reference it with a `<script...>` tag in all of your pages ... `<script src="yourtemplate.js"></script>`

Comment: but it's JS not CSS ;) but ... CSS is only stylesheet, you can't and new element to DOM - only "pseudo element" like :before, :after ... in other words, you can't add <nav> tag but you can populate it using :before and :after  ... but do not learn that type of coding XD